# Subversion projects changes not showing up

Tags: svn

I am new to Subversion, just recently installed it on our server.
I imported a existing web project we have been working on. I am able to check out files edit them update them and commit them. Everything seems OK in subversion.
If I login to my repository in a browser it will show me my changes in the code.

But it does not change the original web project folder that imported.
It should show it right? 
Am I missing a step?

Comment: Hi, did you "svn add" your created files ? When you committed did you see some updated (U) or created (A) status in front of your files ? Did you try to create a new local copy of your svn and get the latest modifications ?

Answer (score 1):

Local files are only updated when

1. the local directory is a *SVN work directory*,
2. you call `svn update` in the directory.

No, the source directory you imported from is not automagically updated, because it is neither of the above. You fed its contents to the SVN repository. Then you checked out the sources to a *different* directory (I assume). This is a *SVN work directory* (try `svn info` - if you get info, it's a work directory, if you get an error it is not).

Other people can also check out a work directory from the repository, do their edits, make their commits, get other people's commits by calling `svn update`. But your commits do not automatically change the contents of other directories.

Answer (score 1):

1. The original import source folder doesn't become a working copy.  Check out the project to a different folder.
2. You have to do an `svn update` to pull down changes from the repository.

Answer (score 1):

From a web development perspective, you would need 2 working copies :

1. one on your local machine, which acts as your development environment,
2. one on your server, which is where your public html files are located (the ones viewed when people go to your website).

Then, you make changes on your development environment (working copy 1), commit them to subversion, then update the working copy that is on your server (working copy 2).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to run an `svn checkout` or `svn update` to the web project folder if you want that folder to be up-to-date, it won't be kept up-to-date automatically unless you setup a post-commit hook of some sort or run a cron that regularly updates that folder from svn.